# resize div relative to parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q1k78sw/) is here, and my question is basically how can I get the red rectangle to resize relative to the parent div. In other words, the rectangle should cover the same region of the parent regardless of how its resized.

The parent div and child are canvas and rectangle below.

```
#canvas {
position: relative;

}

.rectangle {
    border: 3px solid red;
    /* background-color: rgba(255, 148, 0, 0.25); */
    position: absolute;
}
```

The red rectangle also extends beyond the parent, which I guess is to do with the absolute position, if possible this should be avoided.

#### EDIT

The reason the rectangle is hardcoded in the fiddle is that in reality its drawn in browser by user and I'm too lazy to put that js in there. The example rectangle is something the user could draw.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this: (remove the inline css from div.rectangle)

```
.rectangle {
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: i forgot to specify in question, but the rectangle in reality is drawn with a mouse, hence the hard coding here for simplicity.